# GetWindowtext returning nothing

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to learn how to make a GUI for a C++ using visual studio. I’ trying to create a button that when you push it a textbox with the content of a edit window appear, but the GetWindowText function is Returning a blank string when I run my program. I have tried to adjust the size of the buffer to see if that is the problem, but I haven’t been able to solve it that way. I have tried using number instead of the GetWindowTextLength() funktion, but I could not get it to work that way.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{`      HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFile = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hOptions = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFile, L"File");
    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, NULL, L"Edit");
    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hOptions, L"Options");

    AppendMenu(hFile, MF_STRING, NULL, L"Exit");
    AppendMenu(hOptions, MF_STRING, NULL, L"option 1");
    AppendMenu(hOptions, MF_STRING, NULL, L"option 2");

    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenubar);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Hello"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        10, 10, 80, 25,
        hWnd, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON1, NULL, NULL);

    static HWND hWndTextbox = CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT("sim"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        90, 120, 300, 20,
        hWnd, (HMENU) ID_TEXT3, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("shiny"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        50, 50, 80, 50,
        hWnd, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON2, NULL, NULL);
}
break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON1) {
        MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Button has been clicked"), TEXT("title for popup"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON2) {
        // create some default vars
        // Allocate buffer including terminating null

        int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWndTextbox) + 1;
        std::wstring uinput(GetWindowTextLength(hWndTextbox) + 1, 0);

        // Address of first character is used to obtain pointer to non-const data
        // (as opposed to wstring::c_str()).
        int size = GetWindowText(hWndTextbox, &uinput[0], length+1);

        // Resize buffer to the actual text length
        uinput.resize(size);

        // MessageBox only needs pointer to const string, so we can use wstring::c_str() here.
        MessageBox(hWnd, uinput.c_str(), TEXT("Message box"), MB_OK);

    }
    break;
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}`
```

the rest of the code was auto generated by visual studio so I have only included the part where I made changes

Comment: You don't  check return values for errors. Always a mistake. Some debugging would help you. You'll find that the multiple variables named hWndTextbox are the root of the problem. Do try to debug.

Comment: thanks that helped me solve my error.